# overlapping labels in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This might be closed for being too localised, in which case I don't know where to get help from but here goes.

I am drawing a histogram with Tikz (using the ybar interval bar chart) and labelling the bars on the x axis. The problem is that one of the bars is very thin, and as a result the labels merge into one another making them unreadable.

Is there any way to move just one label down so that it sits below the others, preferably with a line above indicating where it should be.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
  xticklabels={BT,UO,HH1,AOM,WS,D,GS,TSZ,BGE,GM,CW,TI,AC,EH,NCW},
  ymin=0,
  width=20cm, height=15cm,
  enlargelimits={false}%
  ]
  \addplot coordinates
    {(0,0.001690154) (0.42008,0.001788549) (1.46562,0.001654645)
    (2.32381,0.0008229) (2.66407,0.000605811) (3.07674,0.00032906)
    (3.89726,0.000320221) (4.67797,0) (5.52977,0.000493147)
    (6.11783,0.000287141)
    (6.57057,0.000686841) (6.81808,0.001095676) (7.07363,0.002101944) 
    (7.11169,0.000255776) (7.22898,0.000594904) (7.53155,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option would be to use some `pin`s for the problematic labels (not that I am very happy with the result):

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.25}]
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
  xticklabels={BT,UO,HH1,AOM,WS,D,GS,TSZ,BGE,GM,CW,TI,,,NCW},
  ymin=0,
  width=20cm, height=15cm,
  clip=false,
  enlargelimits={false}%
  ]
  \addplot coordinates
    {(0,0.001690154) (0.42008,0.001788549) (1.46562,0.001654645)
    (2.32381,0.0008229) (2.66407,0.000605811) (3.07674,0.00032906)
    (3.89726,0.000320221) (4.67797,0) (5.52977,0.000493147)
    (6.11783,0.000287141)
    (6.57057,0.000686841) (6.81808,0.001095676) (7.07363,0.002101944) 
    (7.11169,0.000255776) (7.22898,0.000594904) (7.53155,0)};
    \node[small dot,pin={[pin distance=0.8cm]273:{EH}}] at (axis description cs:0.95,0) {};
    \node[small dot,pin=270:{AC}] at (axis description cs:0.9415,0) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the `|-` tikz notation could give a better result.

Answer (score 9):

A pragmatic (that is to say, not very proper) way to do this is to introduce a blank line in the labels in question, for instance by replacing the `AC` label with `{\\[4pt]AC}`. Note you also have to set `xticklabel style={align=center}` for this to work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
  xticklabels={BT,UO,HH1,AOM,WS,D,GS,TSZ,BGE,GM,CW,TI,{\\[4pt]AC},EH,{\\[4pt]NCW}},
  xticklabel style={align=center},
  ymin=0,
  width=20cm, height=15cm,
  enlargelimits={false}%
  ]
  \addplot coordinates
    {(0,0.001690154) (0.42008,0.001788549) (1.46562,0.001654645)
    (2.32381,0.0008229) (2.66407,0.000605811) (3.07674,0.00032906)
    (3.89726,0.000320221) (4.67797,0) (5.52977,0.000493147)
    (6.11783,0.000287141)
    (6.57057,0.000686841) (6.81808,0.001095676) (7.07363,0.002101944) 
    (7.11169,0.000255776) (7.22898,0.000594904) (7.53155,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, that was quick. I tried something like this with just \\ but didn't realise you needed curly brackets round the label. Thank you.